# response.json() works fine with GET, but throws an error after POST fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I use this custom hook for fetch calls in ReactJS.

```
const useHttp = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const sendRequest = useCallback(async (requestConfig, applyData, notifyErr, notifySuccess) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(requestConfig.url, {
        method: requestConfig.method ? requestConfig.method : "GET",
        headers: requestConfig.headers ? requestConfig.headers : {},
        body: requestConfig.body ? JSON.stringify(requestConfig.body) : null,
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      applyData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      setError(err.message || "Something went wrong!");
    }

    if (notifySuccess) {
      notifySuccess();
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return {
    isLoading,
    error,
    sendRequest,
  };
};
```

When I call a GET method, the sendRequest function runs as expected. But if I call it with POST method, the fetch returns a response and when .json() is called on that response, it throws this error:

```
Unexpected token 'O', "OK" is not valid JSON
```

I've tried logging the response to console. 'OK' is stored in response.statusText, but I don't understand why the .json() targets statusText.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using `nodejs` as backend? Did you `res.send("OK")`rather than `res.json({ success: true })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual HTTP response is only the string "OK". You can see it in the network tab. The method `response.json()` will convert only that HTTP response to JSON. So you can image the code will end up being something like this:

```js
JSON.parse("OK");
```

And this ofcourse throws an error. HTTP responses are basically all strings, but we can parse them to mean other things like a object with `JSON.parse()`.

Long story short, if you know the endpoint won't return any JSON don't parse them with JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Everything works fine after some improvements based on your advice.